# Digital clock with images

Tags: javascript

I want to make a digital clock with images, but i don't know where to start.
The project consist to replace clock number with images on 24 hours style.

From 7 to 20 (need to show blue numbers) (Open) From 20 to 7 (need to show red numbers) (Closed).

I'm trying to work around with the w3c exemple "https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock"

But i don't know how to replace numbers with images in 2 diffrents array. It's need to be only in javascript because it's what i'm trying to learn.

I don't know if my question is clear but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so just how we got the time as a string, I suggest taking each letter of the string and use an image to represent each letter using HTML img tags (which we can generate using pure javascript). Check out the example below. I hope it helps.

```js
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  //this variable contains the time as a string
  var string = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  //this converts string to a set of HTML img tags containing images
  var img = stringToImage(string);
  //this puts the time on the website
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    string + "<br>" + img;
  //this loops the function every 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  } // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}

//This function takes each letter of an array and pairs it to an image of the img array 
function stringToImage(s) {
  //create a temporary blank variable to hold HTML images
  var temp = ""
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    //we take the URL from array img and shove it into an HTML img tag
    //also append it to the temporary variable
    temp = temp + "<img src='" + img[s[i]] + "'/>"
  }
  //uncomment below line to see what the temporary variable says
  //console.log(temp)
  return temp
}


//all image URLs are put into this array. feel free to change URLs
var img = {
  "1": "http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/numbers120/number1.jpg",
  "2": "http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/numbers120/number2.jpg",
  "3": "http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/numbers120/number3.jpg",
  "4": "http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/numbers120/number4.jpg",
  "5": "http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/numbers120/number5.jpg",
  "6": "http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/numbers120/number6.jpg",
  "7": "http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/numbers120/number7.jpg",
  "8": "http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/numbers120/number8.jpg",
  "9": "http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/numbers120/number9.jpg",
  "0": "http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/numbers120/number0.jpg",
  ":": "https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.colonsemicolon.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F02%2Fcolon.gif&f=1"
}

//credit images to:
//http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/pictures/numbers.html
//http://www.colonsemicolon.com/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="topic.js">-->
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">

  <div id="txt"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
setInterval(test,1000);
  function test()
  {
   $("body").load('#ch');
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1"> -->
 <script>
  
 </script>

</head>
<body>
<center>
 <h1>Digital Clock</h1>
 <hr>
 <div id="ch"><?php date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); echo date('h:i:s A e'); ?></div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```