# Clock made out of video's. How to make it start faster and how to make it show the actual time all day? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, video, time, clock

In an earlier post, I mentioned the clock I was looking for. Now I learned the basics of JavaScript and started coding myself.

The goal is to make a 'Maarten Baas' clock (https://vimeo.com/171061144) with the kids attending my technology and design class. The kids will act like the man in the clock, record it on video, and all the videos together will show the clock.

Because all digits are a different set of videos, I made a table of columns containing a separate video. It's now starting to work, but I run into some issues:

1. It takes a while before the clock starts. Why is that? Are all MP4's preloaded? Only when refreshing the page after a few minutes, the clock is showing.
2. The clock is not keeping up to date. It only shows the time that it's loaded. When I refresh the page, it shows the actual time. I tried using `setInterval`, but then it restarts all MP4's every second. Instead, I would like to have the time checked every second and only reload an MP4 if it's the right time for that.

Until now, I really like to code. But I think I've reached my limits for now. Is there anyone that will help me out?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <video width="150" autoplay="true" id="decHour">
              <source src="" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
          </td>

          <td>
            <video width="150" autoplay="true" id="hour">
              <source src="" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
          </td>

          <td>:</td>

          <td>
            <video width="150" autoplay="true" id="decMin">
              <source src="" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
          </td>

          <td>
            <video width="150" autoplay="true" id="min">
              <source src="" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

  <script>
    const hour = new Array();
    hour[0] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour0.mp4";
    hour[1] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour1.mp4";
    hour[2] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour2.mp4";
    hour[3] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour3.mp4";
    hour[4] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour4.mp4";
    hour[5] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour5.mp4";
    hour[6] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour6.mp4";
    hour[7] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour7.mp4";
    hour[8] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour8.mp4";
    hour[9] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour9.mp4";
    hour[10] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour0.mp4";
    hour[11] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour1.mp4";
    hour[12] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour2.mp4";
    hour[13] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour3.mp4";
    hour[14] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour4.mp4";
    hour[15] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour5.mp4";
    hour[16] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour6.mp4";
    hour[17] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour7.mp4";
    hour[18] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour8.mp4";
    hour[19] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour9.mp4";
    hour[20] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour0.mp4";
    hour[21] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour1.mp4";
    hour[22] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour2.mp4";
    hour[23] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour3.mp4";

    const min = new Array();
    min[0] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min0.mp4";
    min[1] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min1.mp4";
    min[2] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min2.mp4";
    min[3] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min3.mp4";
    min[4] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min4.mp4";
    min[5] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min5.mp4";
    min[6] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min6.mp4";
    min[7] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min7.mp4";
    min[8] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min8.mp4";
    min[9] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min9.mp4";
    min[10] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min0.mp4";
    min[11] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min1.mp4";
    min[12] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min2.mp4";
    min[13] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min3.mp4";
    min[14] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min4.mp4";
    min[15] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min5.mp4";
    min[16] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min6.mp4";
    min[17] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min7.mp4";
    min[18] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min8.mp4";
    min[19] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min9.mp4";
    min[20] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min0.mp4";
    min[21] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min1.mp4";
    min[22] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min2.mp4";
    min[23] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min3.mp4";
    min[24] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min4.mp4";
    min[25] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min5.mp4";
    min[26] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min6.mp4";
    min[27] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min7.mp4";
    min[28] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min8.mp4";
    min[29] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min9.mp4";
    min[30] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min0.mp4";
    min[31] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min1.mp4";
    min[32] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min2.mp4";
    min[33] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min3.mp4";
    min[34] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min4.mp4";
    min[35] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min5.mp4";
    min[36] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min6.mp4";
    min[37] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min7.mp4";
    min[38] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min8.mp4";
    min[39] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min9.mp4";
    min[40] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min0.mp4";
    min[41] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min1.mp4";
    min[42] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min2.mp4";
    min[43] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min3.mp4";
    min[44] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min4.mp4";
    min[45] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min5.mp4";
    min[46] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min6.mp4";
    min[47] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min7.mp4";
    min[48] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min8.mp4";
    min[49] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min9.mp4";
    min[50] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min0.mp4";
    min[51] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min1.mp4";
    min[52] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min2.mp4";
    min[53] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min3.mp4";
    min[54] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min4.mp4";
    min[55] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min5.mp4";
    min[56] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min6.mp4";
    min[57] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min7.mp4";
    min[58] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min8.mp4";
    min[59] = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min9.mp4";

    const huidigeTijd = new Date();
    const h = huidigeTijd.getHours();
    const m = huidigeTijd.getMinutes();
    const dHour = document.getElementById("decHour");
    const dMin = document.getElementById("decMin");

    //show decimal hours.

    (function () {
      if (h >= 0 && h < 10) {
        dHour.src = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/decHour0.mp4";
      } else if (h >= 10 && h < 20) {
        dHour.src = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/decHour1.mp4";
      } else {
        dHour.src = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/decHour2.mp4";
      }
    })();

    // show decimal minutes.
    (function () {
      if (m >= 0 && m < 10) {
        dMin.src = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/decMin0.mp4";
      } else if (m >= 10 && m < 20) {
        dMin.src = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/decMin1.mp4";
      } else if (m >= 20 && m < 30) {
        dMin.src = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/decMin2.mp4";
      } else if (m >= 30 && m < 40) {
        dMin.src = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/decMin3.mp4";
      } else if (m >= 40 && m < 50) {
        dMin.src = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/decMin4.mp4";
      } else {
        dMin.src = "https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/decMin5.mp4";
      }
    })();
    // show hours and minutes
    document.getElementById("hour").src = hour[h];
    document.getElementById("min").src = min[m];
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: *"The goal is to make a 'Maarten Baas' clock (https://vimeo.com/171061144) with the kids attending my technology and design class"* - ok please don't take this the wrong way, I mean no offence at all... but for the love of God don't use `<video>` elements for this, and don't teach people to do this kind of thing like this. This is a slow, overengineered and hacky solution that doesn't make sense in the modern web development world. You should check out the [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) instead.

Comment: I get what you say.  But the whole project is about making the video's. (kids attend other coding projects using block code apps like Scratch) I'm just searching for a solution to present the video's in a nice way by coding a little script. I think this can be done eassier and better then i'm doing right now. The original 'Maarten Baas' clock are all videos of 12 hours. That's a bit to long for us, so I thought there should be a quicker way by making video's that last 1 minute, up to 1hour and show them in the right sequence.

Answer (score 0):

For 1, although just list them in code doesn't cause a preload, it's not like you'd need minutes to load a short video, you may try

- Add `muted` so browser doesn't block the autoplay
- Use [`load()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/load) after update `src`
- Use [`play()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play) to start play

For 2, you only update the `src` when it do need change.

```js
const sec = [
  document.getElementById('sec1'),
  document.getElementById('sec0'),
]
sec[1].defaultPlaybackRate = 3

function get_src(sec) {
  return [
    `https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/decMin${Math.floor(sec / 10)}.mp4`,
    `https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min${sec%10}.mp4`,
  ]
}

setInterval(() => {
  const time = new Date()
  const s = time.getSeconds()
  let new_src = get_src(s)
  
  for(let i of [0,1]){
    if(sec[i].src != new_src[i]){
      sec[i].src = new_src[i]
      sec[i].load()
      sec[i].play()
    }
  }
}, 3500) // because your video is too long for 1 sec
```

```html
<video width="150" id="sec1" autoplay muted></video>
<video width="150" id="sec0" autoplay muted></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your support.

This really helps me.
I tweaked the code a little to show the complete time.
In the live clock I will not be using the seconds but for know they are convenient because they show what happens right away (instead of having to wait for minutes until something changes in the time).

The only thing I have to do now is to manage the hours.
The 3 in 03 and 13 hours changes to 4. The 3 in 23 hours changes to 0.
I think I might use the if-else function.
if time = >=0 <=22 show 3.mp4 (script of @apple apple)
else show 3a.mp4

Something to do this weekend.
(the mp4's I'm using are just samples and will be changed)
for now the script is:

```js
function Time() {
  {
    const sec = [
      document.getElementById('sec1'),
      document.getElementById('sec0'),
    ]
    sec[1].defaultPlaybackRate = 3

    function get_src(sec) {
      return [
        `https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/decMin${Math.floor(sec / 10)}.mp4`,
        `https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min${sec%10}.mp4`,
      ]
    }

    setInterval(() => {
      const time = new Date()
      const s = time.getSeconds()
      let new_src = get_src(s)

      for (let i of [0, 1]) {
        if (sec[i].src != new_src[i]) {
          sec[i].src = new_src[i]
          sec[i].load()
          sec[i].play()
        }
      }
    }, 1000)
  }

  //minuten
  {
    const min = [
      document.getElementById('min1'),
      document.getElementById('min0'),
    ]
    min[1].defaultPlaybackRate = 3

    function get_src(min) {
      return [
        `https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/decMin${Math.floor(min / 10)}.mp4`,
        `https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/min${min%10}.mp4`,
      ]
    }

    setInterval(() => {
      const time = new Date()
      const s = time.getMinutes()
      let new_src = get_src(s)

      for (let i of [0, 1]) {
        if (min[i].src != new_src[i]) {
          min[i].src = new_src[i]
          min[i].load()
          min[i].play()
        }
      }
    }, 1000)
  }

  //uren
  {
    const hour = [
      document.getElementById('uur1'),
      document.getElementById('uur0'),
    ]
    hour[1].defaultPlaybackRate = 3

    function get_src(hour) {
      return [
        `https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/decHour${Math.floor(hour / 10)}.mp4`,
        `https://klok.martijndewinter.nl/vid/hour${hour%10}.mp4`,
      ]
    }

    setInterval(() => {
      const time = new Date()
      const s = time.getHours()
      let new_src = get_src(s)

      for (let i of [0, 1]) {
        if (hour[i].src != new_src[i]) {
          hour[i].src = new_src[i]
          hour[i].load()
          hour[i].play()
        }
      }
    }, 1000)
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="time.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="Time()"></body>
<video width="150" id="uur1" autoplay muted></video>
<video width="150" id="uur0" autoplay muted></video>
<img src="dubbelepunt.jpg" width="" height="30">
<video width="150" id="min1" autoplay muted></video>
<video width="150" id="min0" autoplay muted></video>
<img src="dubbelepunt.jpg" width="" height="30">
<video width="150" id="sec1" autoplay muted></video>
<video width="150" id="sec0" autoplay muted></video>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you answering your own question or are you mistakenly assuming this is a forum thread where you're free to wander of in new directions and/or report progress / start a new question? In the latter case, please be informed that is not the model a Q/A site like Stack Overflow follows. See the [help] for extra guidance.